# Socket.CloseAndDispose returns "Invalid Argument was Supplied"

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, .net-4.0, windows-services

I am working on a Windows Service that listens to a single port and based on the data received binds the socket to the relevant Windows Service. Currently we are hosting some of our customers and for every instance of our software we have to allocate a new port to listen on.

[So I read up on `Socket.DuplicateAndClose(...)`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/malarch/archive/2005/12/14/503884.aspx) and it is exactly what I need in this scenario. The only problem is that I cannot figure out why I can't pass in any other PID other than the current running one.

I worked around this by making the service create AppDomains for each service it manages and I use named pipes to pass the `SocketInformation` to each service - this works great. But I'd prefer to keep the services separate.

Can anyone help me on this? Thanks.

Comment: it might be helpful to post the code that generates the exception

Comment: @aw04 Really, it's just one line of code: `socket.DuplicateAndClose(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id)` - this works and is currently what I use (running service inside AppDomain), however change `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id` to a different process ID and it will throw an exception.

Comment: Why should this work?  Processes are not allowed to close other processes' sockets.

Comment: "why I can't pass in any other PID other than the current running one." What happens if you pass in a differrent PID? Describe the error.

Comment: @usr The error is in the title of the question. It simply throws an "Invalid Argument was Supplied".

Comment: @KevinPanko I'm not closing the socket of a different process, I am duplicating it and closing it on the current process - it does actually work, in the same process; across an AppDomain. The method allows for entering a different PID but I can't seem to get it work.

Comment: Sounds like a permissions issue. You probably can't just duplicate data into any process. The docs do not make any statements about permissions, though.